# Pretty URLs in Wicket without mount-path

Tags: java, wicket

The Problem:
Using one of Wickets url mounting strategies I can do the following url (as an example)

`http://somedomain.com/mount-path/desiredname`

what I would like to do is

`http://somedomain.com/desiredname`

desiredname would be e.g. pages or posts. But with Wicket I must use a mount-path first.

Can anybody point me into the right direction, either using a different mounting strategy or a filter setup.

E.g a fallback class for all urls within somedomain.com, from thereone the code should be simple.

thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this blog post answers your question :) [http://blog.jteam.nl/2010/02/24/wicket-root-mounts/](http://blog.jteam.nl/2010/02/24/wicket-root-mounts/)

Comment: this is excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might try to use [Wicketstuff annotation](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Annotation) library

```
@MountPath(path = "/")
@MountMixedParam(parameterNames = { "action", "accountID" })
```

Also you can implement custom [AbstractRequestTargetUrlCodingStrategy](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.4.x/org/apache/wicket/request/target/coding/AbstractRequestTargetUrlCodingStrategy.html)

I'm not sure in this advices.

Answer (score 0):

But if you map your Wicket Filter to "/", won't it work as you expect?

If not, this is probably what you need:

http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Comment: thank you for the link.

wicket filter mapping is set to: <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

when I mount with mount-path it's no problem. All other urls result in a 404. (and catching a 404 to find a specific site as a regualr usecase does not seem that elegant).

Comment: this works if you use both filters and set the url rewrite to redirect. otherwise the wicket filter does not recognize the rewritten url.

Comment: *bump* just see the new answer I posted